# Constant Time std::unordered_map<size_t, size_t> and personal hashmap implementation

Tags: c++, hashmap

I implemented my own hashmap and I wanted to benchmark it vs std::unordered_map. I use functions like the following to measure the nanoseconds it takes to do setting, successful gets, and unsuccessful gets:

```
size_t umap_put_speed(std::unordered_map<size_t, size_t> &umap, size_t key, size_t value){
    auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    umap[key] = value;
    auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto ns_int = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(t2 - t1);
    return ns_int.count();
}

size_t umap_get_speed(std::unordered_map<size_t, size_t> &umap, size_t key){
    auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    umap.find(key);
    auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto ns_int = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(t2 - t1);
    return ns_int.count();
}

size_t single_put_speed(HashMap<size_t, size_t, GenericHash<size_t> > &hmap, size_t key, size_t value){
    auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    hmap.put(key, value);
    auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto ns_int = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(t2 - t1);
    return ns_int.count();
}

size_t single_get_speed(HashMap<size_t, size_t, GenericHash<size_t> > &hmap, size_t key){
    size_t value;
    auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    hmap.get(key, value);
    auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto ns_int = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(t2 - t1);
    return ns_int.count();
}
```

I then write the times to a CSV file as follows:

```
void test_put_speed(){
    std::ofstream benchmark_put;
    benchmark_put.open("benchmarks/put.csv");
    
    benchmark_put << "Num Entries,Linear Map,Unordered Map\n";
    
    // Declare hashmaps
    HashMap<size_t, size_t, GenericHash<size_t> > lmap(SMALL_SIZE);
    std::unordered_map<size_t, size_t> umap;
    
    // Put times
    size_t time_lmap_put = 0;
    size_t time_umap_put = 0;
    
    size_t count = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < MAX_ELEM; i++){
        if(count == WINDOW_SIZE){
            benchmark_put << i << ", ";
            benchmark_put << time_lmap_put/(count) << ", ";
            benchmark_put << time_umap_put/(count) << "\n";
    
            time_lmap_put = 0;
            time_umap_put = 0;
    
            count = 0;
        }
    
        time_lmap_put += lmap_put_speed(lmap, i, i);
        time_umap_put += umap_put_speed(umap, i, i);
    
        count += 1;
    }    
}
```

However, I get the following nanoseconds for insertion, successful searches, and unsuccessful searches:

[image: Benchmark Graphs. Linear Map is my implementation]

I know that hashmaps are designed to take on average O(1) time, but for over a million items, I would have thought that the items I'm adding would leak from the cache into main memory, causing accesses to be slower. Is there something that I'm doing wrong fundamentally? Or is my understanding of why I'm expecting performance to be slower incorrect?

Comment: Does `hmap.get(key, value);` insert a new value? That's what you're doing with `umap[key] = value;`. That, or you are mutating an existing element.

Comment: Please note, `high_resolution_clock` is not guaranteed to be monotonic. You need `steady_clock`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux No, it only queries the entries in hmap, and writes the value into value if the key exists

Comment: Hash tables rarely fit in cache to begin with, so I am not sure why you are asking about "leaking from cache into main memory".

Comment: @AlexPeniz Then you aren't really comparing the same thing. You should use `umap.find(key)` for a more accurate comparison.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think I didn't provide the correct examples. I updated the post with all the functions I wrote. I compare put(key, value) to umap[key] = value and get(key, value) to find(key)

Comment: @AlexPeniz It may still be slightly more accurate to compare `put(key, value)` with `emplace(key, value)`.

Comment: Can you please clarify what your expectation is vs. what you are seeing?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Will do!

Comment: godbolt shows umap_get_speed gets optimized to nothing so that's a measurement of a call to now(). https://godbolt.org/z/hEo1ETTq1

Comment: @JeffGarrett could you explain a little more? I'm assuming now() is just how fast it can tick a single time. If that was the case, then how are the times for umap slower than for hmap?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I just added some graphs that I got with my implementation

Comment: In the version I responded to hmap get, umap get, and hmap put had approximately the same times, and umap put was much longer. Since I have access to umap, I put it on godbolt and see that umap get isn't testing anything (no umap operations are left -- it calls now() twice with nothing in between), but umap put was not completely optimized away. I would infer that because of the similar times, hmap get and put weren't measuring anything either.

Comment: @JeffGarrett That's strange, how would I improve the function to better test an insertion speed? Chain multiple insertions?

Comment: @AlexPeniz This is a good question but it is very hard to answer. As an example Jeff notes that optimisation removes your entire function call. It can do that because your don't actually use the returned value in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this isn't a solution per se, it is how I ended up getting some results that I was more happy with. I changed two things. First, instead of measuring individual insertions, lookups, and removals, I measured the time it took to chain K operations together. This gave me a much clearer picture of how much faster/slower my implementation was compared to unordered_map. My new functions looked like the following:

```
double umap_insert_speed(std::unordered_map<size_t, size_t> &umap, std::vector<size_t> keys){
    auto t1 = steady_clock::now();
    for(size_t key : keys){
        umap[key] = 1;    
    }
    auto t2 = steady_clock::now();
    duration<double> s_double = t2 - t1;
    return s_double.count();
}
```

This generated graphs like the following:

[image]

The second thing I changed was how to get around my timing function not even calling the emplace functions. I simply added a running sum to the loop so I would be using the emplaced values:

```
double umap_emplace_speed(std::unordered_map<size_t, size_t> &umap, std::vector<size_t> keys){
    size_t value;
    size_t sum = 0;
    auto t1 = steady_clock::now();
    for(size_t key: keys){
        umap.emplace(key, value);
        sum += value;
    }
    auto t2 = steady_clock::now();
    duration<double> s_double = t2 - t1;
    return s_double.count();
}
```